# Error Saving File - Invalid Argument in RStudio

Tags: r, save, rstudio

I seem to be unable to save any files in R after a longer sequence of errors.

First: I was not able to generate plots or any graphs and given an error. I tried restarting R (multiple times) and that did not help. I then cleared some space on my computer and this solved that issue.

Next: I was given errors regarding autosaving and told that I may need to restart R. I then restarted R again and then when trying to manually save my file I was given the error "Error Saving File Error Saving ~/Desktop/Stats/FileName.R: Invalid Argument".

I had been working on a project for a few hours before the error occurred. I am running OS Catalina 10.15.7 and RStudio: 2022.07.1+554

Full version description:

```
RStudio 2022.07.1+554 "Spotted Wakerobin" Release (7872775ebddc40635780ca1ed238934c3345c5de, 2022-07-22) for macOS
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.10 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36
```

For now I will keep copy and pasting my code into a google docs file to save.
What can be done to address this?

Thank you.

I cleared storage on my computer assuming that my computer didn't have the storage to create plots (this was accurate as I only had a few MB left. Now I have 3GB). I restarted RStudio multiple times per the prompt instructions and this did not do anything. Now the problem has shifted from not being able to produce graphs to being unable to autosave and save manually either. It seems that code execution is fine - so far.

Code below:

```
    setwd("/Users/name/Desktop/Stats")
    data <-read.table("RealEstateSales.txt", header=T)
    attach(data)
    data

    Age <- 2002 - X7
    Age

    Df2 <- data.frame(Y,X1,X6,X9,Age) #Create D.f. omitting 
    # irrelevant variables
    Df2

    #X9 is coded 1-11 for architecture style
    #X6 is coded 1/0. 1 for having a pool, 0 for not having a 
    #pool
    #Y is sales price, X1 is square footage 
    plot(X1, Y)
    table(X6) 
    table(X9)
    plot(Age,Y)

    library(caTools)
    set.seed(1234567890) 
    inx <- sample.split(seq_len(nrow(Df2)), 400)
    traind <- Df2[inx, ]  
    nrow(traind) 
    testd <- Df2[!inx, ]
    nrow(testd)

    table(X6)

    table(X9)
    hist(X9)

    plot(X1, Y)
    f1 <- factor(X6)
    plot(X1, Y, pch = 20, col =  c("red", "blue")[f1])

    f2 <- factor(X9)
    plot(X1, Y, pch = 20, col = c("red", "blue", "black", 
           "green", "purple", "orange", "cyan", "maroon", 
           "cyan1","brown1","chocolate4")[f2])

    interaction.plot(X1, Age, Y, lwd = 3)

    plot(Age, Y)
    plot(Age, Y, pch = 20, col =  c("red", "blue")[f1])

    plot(Age, Y, pch = 20, col = c("red", "blue", "black", 
              "green", "purple","orange", "cyan", "maroon", 
              "cyan1","brown1","chocolate4")[f2])

    boxplot(Y ~ X6) 
    tapply(Y, X6, mean) 
    t.test(Y ~ X6)

    boxplot(Y ~ X9)
    tapply(Y, X9, mean)

    summary(aov(Y ~ X9))

    tapply(Df2$Y, list(Df2$X6,Df2$X9), mean)
    plot(X9,Y,pch = 20, col =  c("red", "blue")[f1])

    Dfsub1 <- subset(Df2, select= c('Y', 'X1', 'Age')) 
    cor(Dfsub1)

    a <- table(X9,X6) 
    fisher.test(a) 
    chisq.test(a,simulate.p.value = TRUE)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to post your code, just to double-check.

Comment: How exactly are you saving your file? Are you doing File..Save from the GUI menu? Is the error in the console or the RStudio user interface? If the latter, maybe a screen shot would make it more clear where the problem is coming from?

Comment: I can't imagine with the IDE has to do with this. Without code or a concrete example of the issue you're running into, we can't help you.

Comment: @DuckPyjamas, how would I upload my code? Forgive me as I am new to posting on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Phil, how would I upload my code? Forgive me, I am new to posting on stackoverflow.

Comment: You can just copy and paste your code as part of your question. If this is something experiencing regardless of data, provide an example of your code using a readily available dataset like `mtcars`. Also, provide the actual error code you receive (if it is other than the one you already provided).

Comment: @Phil, I copied the code into the question. I am only receiving the error for this project.

Comment: @MrFlick, I am using the save button in the tools ribbon and file > save, and still receiving the same error.

Comment: What are you attempting to name the file? Just "FileName"? What if you give it a name like "myscript.R"?

Comment: @Phil, It's currently named "StatsProject.R". I even attempted using 'save as' and still the same results. Could the file be corrupted somehow? Since my other files can be saved I will just work there for now.

Comment: There would be nothing about a .R file that would get corrupted beyond the text that is saved in it. Try saving it as a .txt file, at least to preserve the code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and what worked for me was to abort the RStudio session by closing the "rsession" icon in the Dock.  I suppose you could also do this via "Session" > "Quit Session...", but make sure to save your code temporarily before that.  This is because some of my most recent changes were lost after that.